# SQL to get max value from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table

Table Plays

```
date     | track_id  | user_id | rating
-----------------------------------------
20170416 | 1         | 1       | 3  (***)
20170417 | 1         | 1       | 5
20170418 | 2         | 1       | 1
20170419 | 3         | 1       | 4
20170419 | 3         | 1       | 2  (***)
20170420 | 1         | 2       | 5
```

What I want to do is for each unique track_id, user_id I want the highest rating row.  I.e. produces this the table below where (***) rows are removed.

```
20170417 | 1         | 1       | 5
20170418 | 2         | 1       | 1
20170419 | 3         | 1       | 2
20170420 | 1         | 2       | 5
```

Any idea what a sensible SQL query is to do this?

Comment: Why for track_id = 3 and user_id = 1 you expect rating = 2, but not 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use MAX built in function along with GROUP by clause :

```
    SELECT track_id, user_id, MAX(rating)
    FROM Your_table
    GROUP BY track_id, user_id;
```

Comment: This is the probably the simplest query. I would also add `ORDER BY date` if that is an additional requirement.

Comment: He wants to have `date` in the result which is missing in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want `max` date as well, try the following:

```
SELECT track_id, user_id, MAX(rating), MAX(date)
FROM plays
GROUP BY track_id, user_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from [table] t1
inner join
(
select track_id, user_id, max(rating) maxRating
from [table]
group by track_id, user_id
) tmp
on t1.track_id = tmp.track_id
and t1.user_id = tmp.user_id
and t1.rating = tmp.maxRating;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have extra columns which is not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause you can go for a subquery like:

```
SELECT track_id,user_id,rating  --, other columns you want to display
FROM(
      SELECT track_id, user_id, rating,ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY track_id, user_id ORDER BY rating DESC) as RN --,Other columns which you want to display
       FROM Your_table 
                        ) X
WHERE X.RN=1
```